# How do I absolutley position a div and have it stay in its original top position with dom elements above it that are floated?

Tags: html, css

I simply want a div that is absolutely positioned to sit at its current offset top positioning, but im realizing that if any element above it in the DOM is floated (even if that element is inside an element that isnt floated) it will snap to the top of the relative parent. as soon as I remove the above floats the absolutley positioned div snaps to the top. any help is greatly appreciated. here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hPA3M/2/

Here is my Html:

```
   <div class="parent">
        <div class="child1">
            <div class="baby1">
                <p>Baby</p>
            </div>
            <div class="baby1">
                <p>Baby</p>
            </div>
            <div class="baby1">
                <p>Baby</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="child2">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my css:

```
    .parent {
        position:relative;
        height:800px;
        width:400px;
        background:#ff0000;
        padding:20px;
    }

    .child1 {
        width:100%;
        background-color:#00ff00;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }

    .baby1 {
        background:#e1e1e1;
        /*
        toggling float on and off has very different effects
        */
        float:left;
        width:30%;
    }

    .child2 {
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        background-color:#0000ff;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here, but unless you give you absolute position div some x and y coordinates, then it's not absolute. I don't see any in your css, therefore the div is simply subject to the cascade.

Comment: regardless of x and y you can apply absolute to pull it out. as you can see in the example, padding isnt applied the same way. its pullout to the level below the nearest relative parent, then its up to you if you want to use top, left, bottom, right. in this instance i wanted to modify the right property without effecting the top positioning in the cascade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` for `.child1` selector:

```
    .child1 {
        width:100%;
        background-color:#00ff00;
        margin-bottom:10px;

    }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hPA3M/4/)

Comment: Interesting, what is this overflow:hidden actually doing here?

Comment: Here is a complete answer on your question http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: actually read this from chris's site: "One more popular uses of setting overflow, strangely enough, is float clearing. Setting overflow doesn't clear the float at the element, it self-clears. This means that the element with overflow applied (auto or hidden), will extend as large as it needs to encompass child elements inside that are floated (instead of collapsing), assuming that the height isn't declared." source: http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/. answer excepted! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hPA3M/3/)

When dealing with floating elements is useful to have a `clear:both` below them.
In this case i addedd `<div class="clear"></div>` below `child1`.

CSS for `.clear` is

```
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Yes there're couple of ways to do it. For your knowledge now you know this one too.